# ddrescue attempt ends with drive disappearing from /dev

Tags: linux, data-recovery, opensuse, ddrescue

I have been trying to recover data from a Seagate 7200.11 1.5TB drive (2 ext4 partitions) for 3 days now, predominantly with `ddrescue` and `testdisk`, but because of some critical error on the disk (probably SA damage or something similar?), it gets dropped off `/dev` when the system accesses some specific sector(s).

The closest I have come, I think, is with `ddrescue`. But the image it created was incomplete and I could not mount it as it gave "bad geometry: block count xxx exceeds size of device.." error among others. Last night I again fired up `ddrescue`, this time on the second partition, and after waiting for 3 hours, went to sleep. At that time, it had copied ~150GB from the ~700GB partition.

Command used:

```
ddrescue -n -v -T 30 --skip-size=1M,10M --min-read-rate=50k /dev/sdc2 /media/rescue/Drive2.img /media/rescue/Drive2.log
```

I was pretty disappointed when I woke up and saw that the drive had disappeared from `/dev` and consequently `ddrescue` showed "error size" in 200GB+ range. The `/var/log/messages` contained repeating lines:

```
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526490+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096125] Read(10): 28 00 5a 79 55 88 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526491+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096174] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526491+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096176] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526492+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096176] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526493+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096177] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526494+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096178] Read(10): 28 00 5a 79 4d e8 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T10:54:08.526494+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6693.096226] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
```

and these around the time it disappeared from `/dev` (I think):

```
2014-06-13T07:34:30.290574+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6743.832817] ata3: EH complete
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892459+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432198] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892486+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432203] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892489+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432206] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892502+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432212] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:50:08/00:00:5c:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892511+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432212]          res 41/40:08:17:50:08/00:00:5c:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892517+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432215] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
2014-06-13T07:34:33.892519+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.432217] ata3.00: error: { UNC }
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003455+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543056] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003476+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543074] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003480+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543076] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003483+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543078] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003486+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543080] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003488+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543082] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003491+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543085] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003502+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543086]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003503+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543095]         5c 08 50 17 
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003504+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543099] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003505+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543110] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003505+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543111] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003506+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543112] Read(10): 28 00 5c 08 50 10 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003507+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543116] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1544048663
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003508+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543118] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 3270402
2014-06-13T07:34:34.003509+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6747.543127] ata3: EH complete
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758454+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295735] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758484+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295740] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758488+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295743] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758492+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295750] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:50:08/00:00:5c:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758496+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295750]          res 41/40:08:17:50:08/00:00:5c:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758499+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295752] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
2014-06-13T07:34:36.758502+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.295754] ata3.00: error: { UNC }
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932467+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469333] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932495+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469351] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled sense code
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932501+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469354] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932504+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469355] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932507+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469357] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932510+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469359] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932514+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469362] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932534+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469364]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932546+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469372]         5c 08 50 17 
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932551+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469376] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932556+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469379] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932560+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469381] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932564+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469382] Read(10): 28 00 5c 08 50 10 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932567+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469390] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1544048663
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932572+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469394] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 3270402
2014-06-13T07:34:36.932576+05:00 suse kernel: [ 6750.469420] ata3: EH complete
2014-06-13T07:36:15.441806+05:00 suse su: (to root) procyon on /dev/pts/5
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731456+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286421] ata3: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731483+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286429] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731487+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286431] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731488+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286434] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731490+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286440] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:00:10:59:6d/00:00:60:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731493+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286440]          res 40/00:00:10:59:6d/00:00:60:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
2014-06-13T07:53:20.731495+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.286443] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
2014-06-13T07:53:20.740442+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.296009] ata3.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
2014-06-13T07:53:20.740462+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.296013] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
2014-06-13T07:53:20.740464+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.296018] ata3: hard resetting link
2014-06-13T07:53:21.045453+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.599792] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
2014-06-13T07:53:21.065444+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.620355] ata3.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
2014-06-13T07:53:21.065467+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7873.620359] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
2014-06-13T07:53:26.045451+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.595494] ata3: hard resetting link
2014-06-13T07:53:26.350457+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.900156] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395504+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945713] ata3.00: both IDENTIFYs aborted, assuming NODEV
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395516+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945717] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-2)
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395518+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945719] ata3.00: disabled
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395520+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945752] ata3: EH complete
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395522+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945774] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395523+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945775] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395525+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945776] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395528+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945777] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395529+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945778] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 59 10 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395531+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945782] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617778960
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395532+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945784] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486690
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395534+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945863] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395535+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945868] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395537+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945869] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395538+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945872] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395540+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945873] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 59 10 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395541+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945882] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617778960
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395543+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945885] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486690
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395544+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.945997] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395546+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946000] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395547+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946002] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395548+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946004] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395550+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946005] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 59 80 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395551+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946012] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617779072
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395552+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946015] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486704
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395554+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946076] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395555+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946080] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395557+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946082] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395558+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946085] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395560+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946100] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 5a 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395562+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946141] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617779200
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395563+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946152] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486720
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395580+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946192] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395582+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946194] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395584+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946195] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395585+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946196] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395587+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946197] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 5b 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395588+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946202] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617779456
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395590+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946203] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486752
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395592+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946221] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395593+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946223] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395595+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946224] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395596+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946224] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395598+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946227] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 5d 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395599+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946228] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617779968
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395601+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946229] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486816
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395602+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946245] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395608+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946254] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395611+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946254] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395612+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946255] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395615+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946258] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 61 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395616+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946259] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617780992
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395618+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946260] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12486944
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395624+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946281] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395626+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946282] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395628+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946284] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395629+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946285] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395634+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946286] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 69 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395636+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946295] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617783040
2014-06-13T07:53:26.395637+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946297] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12487200
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396515+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946314] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396522+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946315] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396524+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946316] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396527+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946318] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396529+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946319] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 79 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396531+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946323] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617787136
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396533+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946325] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12487712
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396534+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946344] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396536+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946346] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396538+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946347] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396540+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946348] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396542+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946349] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d 99 00 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396544+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946354] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1617795328
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396546+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946356] Buffer I/O error on device sdc2, logical block 12488736
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396548+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946374] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396550+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946376] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396552+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946377] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396554+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946379] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396556+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946379] Read(10): 28 00 60 6d d9 08 00 00 08 00
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396557+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946401] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396560+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946403] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc]  
2014-06-13T07:53:26.396561+05:00 suse kernel: [ 7878.946404] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out at which block/sector did the issue occur, so I can restart ddrescue from that point on, skipping the troublesome area. For now, The same was the case with testdisk when I tried to list the files for recovery; after I had painstakingly selected all the files to copy, testdisk failed to copy a single one of them because the drive had disappeared during the scanning I think.

For now, I have restarted `ddrescue` with this:

```
ddrescue -n -v -T 30 -A --retrim -d -i 150G --skip-size=500k,10M --min-read-rate=50k /dev/sdc2 /media/rescue/Drive2.img /media/rescue/Drive2.log
```

But as it is bound to repeat the disappearing drive phenomenon again and producing an incomplete/almost-useless image, I really need some help in figuring out a way to skip the sectors that are causing this problem, or any other tips to recover the data.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there any way to prevent a bad drive from disappearing from /dev?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218279/176171)

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling recently with a Seagate disk and ddrescue. The drive kept going offline like you describe above. On a whim I decided to turn off the SMART features on the drive and that did the trick. The disk was still occasionally flaky but I was able to recover data. This is the command I used to turn of the SMART features:

`sudo smartctl --smart=off --offlineauto=off --saveauto=off /dev/sdb`

Comment: Now that's something potentially useful. I'm not able to confirm this, but I don't think you made a joke in this forsaken thread. Chances are the command really worked for you and you wanted to share the knowledge. This should be rewarded, +1 from me.

Comment: For me it needed a -d flag. I tried to do this unsuccessfully via trial-and-error for the -d argument.

Comment: To find the right `-d` flag for your hard disk or USB controller, see [this table](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices). You may also need a `-T permissive`. Once `--info` shows that SMART is disabled, it's disabled.

Comment: This worked for me! I suppose that something in SMART causes the disk to drop offline to protect itself. Unhelpful during a ddrescue, of course. (In my case, it was a cheapo SATA SSD from PNY. I didn't need any flags on the smartctl command.)

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is to use no tool that writes to the drive as that can cause more damage.
So think twice before using tools like Spinrite.

Regarding the drive disappearing with ddrescue. I have seen this many times operating on Seagate drives. It's very frustrating.

Skipping over the problem sectors using ddrescue is the only way I have been able to create a useful image.  The -R -s and -i options help for this but it involves a lot of trial and error.

I understand that hardware imagers like DeepSpar are better able to image such drives.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use SpinRite for data recovery.  Do not write to the failing disk.    Use GNU ddrescue with a log file, and use the option  to try all parts of the disk.  When disk disappears, re-issue the command and it will skip over already copied parts of the drive.     To make the disk reappear, it needs to be powered down and up again.   I have recovered data from my own drive by this method.

Answer (score -2):

Before you spend thousands on data recovery services, I recommend trying SpinRite at GRC.com for $89 dollars. Written by Security Now's Steve Gibson, SpinRite can be used on any operating system and any file system. This means it can run on drives formatted with Windows XP's/Vista's/Windows 7's NTFS and all other older FAT formats (in addition to all Linux, Novell, and all other file systems.)

Follow the instructions download the ISO and create a live CD (or other bootable media), including its own bootable FreeDOS operating system. Run Spinrite at level 2 first and check the missing files. If that doesn't work run at level 5. There is a step-by-step video at https://www.grc.com/sr/whatitdoes.htm

Spinrite is a must have" tools for the computer pro or serious hobbyist. I use it for drive maintenance as well as to pre-qualify and certify unformatted hard drives before first use. Drives on non-PC platforms, such as Apple Macintosh or TiVo, may be temporarily relocated to a PC motherboard for data recovery, maintenance and repair by SpinRite. SpinRite provides complete interaction with IDE-interface PATA (parallel ATA) and SATA (Serial ATA) drives, and it can also be used with any other type of drive — SCSI, USB, 1394/Firewire — that can be made visible to DOS through the addition of controller BIOS or add-on DOS drivers.

After you are done, do your backup. :-)

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement.