# Disabling SMART in Mac

Tags: hard-drive, mac, ssd, smart

I am trying to disable SMART on a Samsung SSD, to follow the advice in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/768377/ddrescue-attempt-ends-with-drive-disappearing-from-dev). I run the following command:

```
sudo smartctl --smart=off /dev/disk4 
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [Darwin 21.4.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Disabled. Use option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
```

However, we can see the SMART is not actually disabled:

```
arden@thedaves-iMac ~ % smartctl -a /dev/disk4              
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [Darwin 21.4.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB
Serial Number:    S6PNNS0RB03234V
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 f31b2874a
Firmware Version: SVT01B6Q
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic, zeroed
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-4 T13/BSR INCITS 529 revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Oct  6 13:12:37 2023 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

I have tried adding various `-d` flags to the command, but I just get the same result. How can I disable SMART on this drive?

Comment: What problem(s) are you trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: This [FAQ](https://smartlinux.sourceforge.net/smart/faq.php?#10) states that SMART needs to be disabled from the BIOS.

Comment: How is the drive connected? Internal, external, USB 2, 3, Thunderbolt? Data says SATA, which would make me assume internal… but doesn't explain how it's disk4 on an iMac with only 2 SATA ports internally. Macs don't carry proper data over USB without some additional work.  https://superuser.com/questions/1616395/smart-check-on-external-usb-hard-disk-on-macos

Comment: Step 1 would be getting rid of USB 'layer' and find a PC where you can hook up the the drive to SATA. Data recovery, bad sectors, unstable drives and USB don't mix well.